# Is it ok to say something like "I will also try my best to help as what I have to offer."

Tags: phrase-usage

I am trying to let the interlocutor I am talking with to know that I will try my best to provide knowledge as much as I know.

Is it a good way to express the idea by "I will also try my best to help as what I have to offer."

Or is there a better way to say?

Comment: Your sentence isn't idiomatic (help as). You could say "...to help _using_ what knowledge I have" (or other versions_.

Comment: @KateBunting So we do not use `help as` right? I just want to express that `I would like to help as much as I can`.

Comment: _Help as much as I can_ is fine. I should have said "We can say 'help _as much'_, but not 'help _as what'"_.

Comment: Or maybe "help **with** what I have to offer."

Comment: Thank you for both! Your advices are really helpful!